# How to shrink a proportional odds model with LASSO?

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to shrink a proportional odds model with LASSO for ordinal regression.  As far as I know, the `penalized` package has no options for ordinal regression. I've found the `glmnetcr` and `glmnet` packages but they are both only suitable for fitting continuation ratio models instead of proportional odds.

Is there another package available to use LASSO for ordinal regression? Or will it be better to use ridge regression in the `lrm` funtion from the `rms` package?